# Liberty Profile Server - Logging and Trace issues

Tags: logging, websphere-liberty

I'm trying to add the logging levels in my WAS Liberty Profile Server 8.5.5.6 hosted in linux environment. 
I've added following statement in the server.xml:

```
<logging consoleLogLevel="INFO" copySystemStreams="true" traceFormat="ENHANCED" traceSpecification="*=audit:com.myco.*=all"/>
```

The configuration provided above works in my eclipse in windows but when deployed in Linux server: GNU/Linux 2.6 it doesn't work. Meaning it is not capturing the INFO level logging.

I use Apache.Commons.logging 1.2

Comment: which part of the logging doesn't work in GNU/Linux?  the consoleLogLevel? the traceSpec?

Comment: INFO level logging is not working. while running the SOAP UI test cases, I do see error in my local eclipse console file (also console and in trace) for error scenario's but not in the log file deployed on server for the same scenarios.

Comment: Do you know if this also happens when you are using java.util.logging or is it only for commons logging?

Comment: I'm now using commons logging. I didn't try with java.util.logging.

Answer (score 0):

You've set the console log level to INFO, but then disabled info level logging:

> traceSpecification="***=audit**:com.myco.*=all"

Try again with the **audit** changed to **info** like this:

> traceSpecification="***=info**:com.myco.*=all"